# BFS, need to create the set once and for all, not everytime

Tags: python, methods, breadth-first-search

Got a problem, I've solved a problem with this code:

```
def hamta():
    ordlista=[]
    fil=open("labb9text.txt")
    ordlista=[]
    for line in fil.readlines():
        ordlista.append(line.strip())
    return ordlista

def setlista():
    ordlista=hamta()
    setlista=set()
    for a in ordlista:
        if a not in setlista:
            setlista.add(a)
    return setlista

def hittabarn(parent):
    mangd=setlista() 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)          #listan måste läsas in en gång för alla, inte i hittabarn
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count==2:
                if word not in children:
                    children.append(word)
            if i>2:
                break
    return children
```

The problem is that everytime I wanna run "hittabarn", I'll have to load call setlista (which means I have to "create" the list with words, and it's not supposed to be like that, the assignment says that I should only load the list once, in the beginning, how do I solve this problem? Is it possible to like give the setlista-method a parameter, and then give hittabarn another parameter? That's what I've been trying but cant really make it work....

Comment: I know it is your choice, but especially if you want others to help you on StackOverflow, your code should probably use english identifiers and should have english comments (and english mixed with another language looks ugly). I'll try to find the problem anyway, so don't worry. But others may not even want to try.

Comment: Where are you calling `setlista` and `hittabarn`?

Comment: I updated it now, I copied the code I was experimenting with, ye, I've realized it was really, really stupid to go both english and swedish here, Im sorry about that, next time I post something here I will stop with that, was really dumb of me

Comment: as you can see I'm calling mangd=setlista() in hittabarn-method (which I dont wanna do)...

Comment: You appear to have inserted some assumptions; since you haven't detailed "a problem" you're solving, we can't help too much.  As it stands, the problem does nothing: there's no entry point to the code you wrote.

Comment: You never call **hittabarn**.  **parent** is undefined.

Comment: Most such applications are wrapped up in a *class*, including an initialization method: something you call *once* on creation; then you maintain those given values in class attributes.

Comment: yes, I realized that, I just updated it, im sorry about that, I copied the wrong code, I copied something I was experimenting with, sorry about that

Comment: Isnt it possible to add a list as paramter in both the setlista method and the hittbarn-method, I'm unsure how to implement it (I tried to but couldnt call it, either I didnt understand how to call it proper or it simply didnt work)

Comment: Prune, I did edit the code as I mentioned above, do you have any ideas of what I can possibly do ?